# devise not creating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hi i have installed devise gem and created the user later on i have used simple_form gem for next to line errors. Now its not creating users, but i can log in by using already created user. Not showing whats happening exactly, showing "Please review the problems below: " but there were no problems list.
My registartions view is,

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :fullname, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <div><%= f.label :date_of_birth, required: true %></br>
    <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth, order: [:day, :month, :year], start_year: 1920 %></div>
  <br />

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My usermodel is,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable

   validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}  
   validates :phone_number, presence: true, length: {maximum: 12} 
   validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
   :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :create
     validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,
   :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :update, allow_blank: true

  validate :at_least_18

def at_least_18
    if self.date_of_birth
      errors.add(:date_of_birth, 'You must be 18 years or older.') if self.date_of_birth > 18.years.ago.to_date
    end
end

   has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for  :users, 
              :path => '', 
              :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
              :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}

  resources :users 

end
```

My registratins controller is,

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    protected
        def update_resource(resource, params)
            resource.update_without_password(params)
        end
end
```

My usercontroller is,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    UserMailer.changepass_email(@user).deliver_now
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'Password was successfully updated.'
  else
    redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user.id), alert: 'Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric'
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

end

Can someone help me to solve the error... It is not even showing the error on the screen, whats happening exactly.

(0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (8.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'royalsaran777@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction

Comment: Can you post the rails log trace ?

Comment: Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-04-29 16:34:22 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 600ms (Views: 580.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Started GET "/sign_up" for ::1 at 2016-04-29 16:34:26 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (145.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 331ms (Views: 311.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: Started POST "/" for ::1 at 2016-04-29 16:34:46 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OpvnPkPTXwQ/5kuFOQdAvNA+niHsomjuUIOTFPDVRVXJ8Efzm64VZfjU67mXhEKoCMDd6Jx4tjTqJvfuDqlNJg==", "user"=>{"fullname"=>"ku", "email"=>"ro77@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "date_of_birth(3i)"=>"1", "date_of_birth(2i)"=>"3", "date_of_birth(1i)"=>"1990"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.5ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'ro77@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction

Comment: Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 318ms (Views: 184.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

Comment: Does a user with email ro77@gmail.com already exist in the database ?

Comment: no.... he does not exists